# What are the types of these CUDA pointer attributes?

Tags: cuda, cuda-driver

The `cuGetPointerAttribute()` is passed a pointer to one of multiple types, filled according to the actual attribute requested. Some of those types are stated explicitly or may be deduced implicitly to deduce, but some - not so much. Specifically... what are the types to which a pointer must be passed for the attributes:

- `CU_POINTER_ATTRIBUTE_BUFFER_ID` - probably a numeric ID, but what's its type?
- `CU_POINTER_ATTRIBUTE_ALLOWED_HANDLE_TYPES` - a bitmask, supposedly, but how wide?

The CUDA driver API doesn't seem to answer these questions.

PS - Even for the boolean attributes it's not made clear enough whether you should pass an `int*` or a `bool*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, the buffer id is stored as unsigned long long:

CU_POINTER_ATTRIBUTE_BUFFER_ID: Returns in *data a buffer ID which is guaranteed to be unique within the process. *data must point to an unsigned long long*.

When I try to pass a `char*` with `CU_POINTER_ATTRIBUTE_ALLOWED_HANDLE_TYPES`, valgrind reports an invalid write of size 8. Passing `std::size_t*` does not cause errors.

Similarly, using `char*` with `CU_POINTER_ATTRIBUTE_IS_LEGACY_CUDA_IPC_CAPABLE`, reports an invalid write of size 4, which is not the case with `int*`

(using NVCC V11.5.119)

Comment: Missed that last bit in the documentation regarding the buffer ID. Good idea about using valgrind to check for the write size... :-)